# Updating Basemaps in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3

I'm getting the sense that OpenLayers 3 does not differentiate between basemaps and other layers the way OpenLayers 2 did (OL2 Layers had a [`isBaseLayer` property](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html), but I'm not seeing an equivalent in OL3).

I'm guessing there must be some way to set the ordering when adding a layer to a map...something like

```
map.addLayer(newBasemap, 1);  // where all other layers would have an ordering greater than 1
```

But when I look at the docs all I see is [`addLayer(layer)`](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.Map.html#addLayer) which places the new layer on top of the other layers.

How can I ensure the new (basemap) layer is placed underneath the other layers rather than on top?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found an answer [here at Christopher Jennison's Blog](http://christopherjennison.com/openlayers-3-beginners-part-2/).

Turns out layers can be added at a particular index with the following:

```
map.getLayers().insertAt(1, layer);
```

In my case in which I'm replacing the basemap that's already there I need to first remove basemap1 and then add basemap2 in its place, which I can do like this:

```
map.removeLayer(basemap1);
map.getLayers().insertAt(1, basemap2);
```

Huzzah

UPDATE:

Thanks to [erilem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1064422/erilem) for providing a more straightforward solution, `setAt`, which simply replaces the layer at a given index...

```
map.getLayers().setAt(1, basemap2);
```

Comment: Note that you can use `map.getLayers().setAt(index, layer)` to replace a layer at a given index by a new one.